# Jasmine Test Promise in Angular Service

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, promise

I am using Dexie for IndexedDB interactions in an Angular app and would like to create some Jasmine unit tests.

My Angular service has the following method:

```
test4: function () {
        return db.Configs.get('ProductsLastSync');
    }
```

which returns a Dexie Promise (an ES6 compatible promise). How would I go about creating a test on the result?

I have tests which that work on angular promises created using the $q service and forcing a digest cycle, but I cannot see how to wire this together.

Comment: Though this post is 1 year old, please provide the existing test code (for any questions in future), too.